# How do I embed a video into a Konami Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok. I understand how to embed a video using scripts and I got the konami code working on my website--it currently has an alert. What I do not understand is how to have a video popup in lightbox or fancybox. Or if that isn't possible, how to link to a page inside my site so they can view the video there.

Current js and jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/konami-JS.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    konami = new Konami()
    konami.code = function() {
        alert("You have entered the KONAMI CODE!  You now have 30 lives.  Kinda.")
    }

konami.load()
</script>
```

This is my site "http://webdesign.miad.edu/stimm/" and as you can see, if you enter the Konami code (up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, b, a, enter), there is currently an alert. So everything works. It's just not what I want.

Any help is appreciated...thank you so much!

Comment: You need to write the code in order to show a video. Get a light box plugin , and video plugin or use the video tag inside the konami.code function. You just need to write the code.

Comment: I know I need to write the code..that's the problem :(. I am just getting into javascript and am not completely sure how to code it correctly. For example, if I set up the script for lightbox or fancybox, how do I implement that into the konami script? Please show examples. I am still learning....

Answer (score 1):

Well if you care only about modern day browsers, you can append a video tag to the page.

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
document.getElementById('WhereYouWantItOnPageId').appendChild(video);
video.setAttribute('src', 'yourMovie.mp4');
video.play();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer :). I apologize, but I am fairly new to coding. Would you mind showing me where that code would be placed? And would that pop out in a small window, go to a new page, or what? In addition, what part of the code you gave me do I need to change?

Comment: put it where the alert is.

Comment: All right. I put it where the alert is. Now what portions of it do I actually need to change? I assume I change the 'WhereYouWantItOnPageId" and the ('src', 'yourMovie.mp4'). Is that correct? And are those the only ones I change?  Lastly, is this directing to a video I have uploaded on my website or is it directing to an outside source?